# XML2HTML tools?

Tags: html, xml, transform

I need to transform XML file into HTML.
What options do I have? Is there any python tool for it?

### ADDED

On my mac, I found **xsltproc**, and I could run it as follows

```
xsltproc xslt.xml hello.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) is for various XML translations. I'm sure you can find Python library for it.